# Why are we allowed to eat flour?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, korban, blood, kaparah-atonement

The Torah explicitly says that we may not eat blood because the blood is an essential element in effecting Kaparah (as explained in [Vayikra 17:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.17.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) among other places):

> כִּי נֶפֶשׁ הַבָּשָׂר בַּדָּם הִוא וַאֲנִי נְתַתִּיו לָכֶם עַל־הַמִּזְבֵּחַ לְכַפֵּר עַל־נַפְשֹׁתֵיכֶם כִּי־הַדָּם הוּא בַּנֶּפֶשׁ יְכַפֵּר׃  For the life of the flesh is in the blood, and I have assigned it to you for making expiation for your lives upon the altar; **it is the blood, as life, that effects expiation**.

But Vayikra 5:11 mentions that, for those who are too poor to afford even birds, one may bring a flour offering which will effect kaparah using parallel language in terms of the presentation and efficacy of the flour.

If that's the case, why isn't the same forbidding of consumption extended to flour, as it serves the same role as the blood in the sacrifice (or some part of it does). In the same way that the blood is the means by which an animal sacrifice is effective, something IN the flour, (not the action of sacrificing something of value) should be that same essence for kaparah and should be forbidden.

How are they different? Is there another reason for forbidding blood related to its being the seat of some life-force (נֶ֣פֶשׁ הַבָּשָׂר֮ בַּדָּ֣ם הִוא֒) which makes it distinct, and the utility of it in terms of sacrifice is not the reason? Is it a special rule for an unstated reason which we don't expand to similar cases because the specific rule does not include other things?

Comment: Isn't the flour more analogous to the meat of the korban?

Comment: It could be but what would be the other section then that is forbidden because it is the essence of the kaparah (in an effort to make the flour offering parallel).

Comment: @rosends The idea of sacrificing an animal or bird is to imagine that, that ought to be happen to you if you have sinned. The flour sin offering cant be looked at that way.

Comment: Not sure why there needs to be such a thing. A mincha doesn't have a component that only serves to effect kappara

Comment: @DoubleAA that may very well be part of the answer I guess. Would that indicate anything deficient in the use of the flour, lacking something that can be tied to "life" in some way?

Comment: @interested same question

Comment: Where does it say that blood can't be consumed because it is essential to kapara?  I understand the verse teaching two separate concepts.  The nefesh is in the Blood and therefore blood atones.  The second that you can't consume blood.  I can see how flour can atone since it is your food like an animal.  But I don't see the connection to the blood, unless the Torah would state that flour is forbidden to consume like it does with blood.

Comment: @AZav_nov The word "ki" seems to make some sort of causal link in the pasuk. If that's not how the "ki" works here and the two are connected in some other way, making the statement about atonement simply coincidental, then I would need to understand that better.